# Issue with NSDateFormatter adjusting time unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Working in Objective-C, I've got a method to properly format a date that I get from a database.
The database returns a date and time with no timezone information. For example '2016-06-07T09:29:50.253'.

The problem is that it was getting the date correctly, then turning it back by an hour. For my time of 09:29 I'd end up with 08:29.

I'm working with BST at the moment.

I have the following code:

```
    +(NSDate *)getDate:(NSString *)date {

//Gets the date
        date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
        date = [date componentsSeparatedByString: @"."][0];

//Formats the date
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//This line is the one that fixes it.
        [formatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        NSDate  *returnDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
        return returnDate;
    }
```

I did a few google searches and found that having added the following line fixes the problem.

```
[formatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

This is fine for the time being, but I'm worried that it'll break again at daylight savings time, and I'm not entirely sure why this fixes it. I had also hoped I'd be able to get it to adjust for different time zones, but as of yet have had no luck.

Further information:

-The date comes from a getDate() call in sql server. My understanding of this is that it takes the date as is, with no understanding of timezone. If I do a select call, I get the result: '2016-06-07T09:29:50.253'

To formalise the question:
**Why might the above code make an adjustment to the returnDate?**

Comment: UTC is a standard, not a time zone. Use GMT for this purpose. More info — http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html

Comment: Please add how you "end up" with 08:29. How are you reading the date? And how are dates stored in the database - at some point a timezone will either be declared or have been agreed upon.

Comment: Why to you remove the `T` and what's after the `.`. Add them to the date format.

Comment: BTW, when storing dates in database like this, it's also prudent to set the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` to ensure consistent format, regardless of the user's localization settings. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's an important difference between an `NSDate` object and it's representation using a formatter:

The `NSDate` object will always be relative to a universal time standard (UTC). It is oblivious to daylight savings and timezones and this is the way you want it to be stored on your database (as a UTC timestamp).

When you use a formatter, it is normally used to display the date to a user. Because of this, the formatter will default to representing the date using your current device's locale, so if you're date is 11:00 and you're in a +4 time-zone with no daylight savings, the date you'll get will be 15:00. If there are daylight savings the time will change slightly. You want this behaviour because this will mean that user's will always get the correct relative time for the date they are looking at no matter where you are in the world.

Unless, as you have, you default the formatter to use a "UTC" locale, which should not be confused with "+0" timezone. This is why you're getting different dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this formatter (instead of removing the T and .):

```
let dateLiteral = "2016-06-07T09:29:50.253"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
formatter.dateFromString(dateLiteral) // Jun 7, 2016, 9:29 AM
```

Comment: You should remove `Z` from your formatter, as there is no `Z` in the date string. Also, FYI, the `'` are only needed around the `T`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for you comments.